# TypeError: filter must be an instance of dict, bson.son.SON, or any other type that inherits from collections.Mapping

Tags: python, django, mongodb, nosql, fastapi

In a Python function If I write like this, I get *Expected expression Pylance* in vscode.

```
    document = await collection.find({'date': {$gte: {start_date}, $lte: {end_date}}}).to_list(100)
```

Here, `date` is my *field* and `sart_date`, `end_date` are the dynamic value that specify the specific range of documents I'd like to get from database.

And, then because of Pylance error, I changed code like this:

```
    query_string = {"date": f'{{date: {{$gte: {start_date}, $lte: {end_date}}}}}'}

    document = await collection.find(query_string["date"]).to_list(100)
```

And also, writing `print(query_string)` I get **{date: {$gte: '2021-07-15T16:18:46.688Z', $lte: '2021-07-18T12:18:45.258Z'}}** on terminal as well that means the value of *query_string* variable is right. Even If I check with this query in mongodb compass gui app, it returns me the desired data from database. So why getting title's error when the function runs? Please, help me up.

> For your convenience, the whole function is:

```js
# routing in FastAPI
@router.get('/api/{start_date}_{end_date}') 
async def query_date_from_person(start_date, end_date):
    query_string = {"date": f'{{date: {{$gte: {start_date}, $lte: {end_date}}}}}'}
    document = await collection.find(query_string["date"]).to_list(100)
    return document
```

Answer (score 1):

No one did help me, fine :)
Finally I solved my own problem and answering because of instant solution for other people in future that I didn't get from the community.

```
@router.get('/api/{start_date}_{end_date}')
async def query_date_from_person(start_date: str, end_date: str):
    document = await collection.find({"date": {"$gte": start_date, 
                                      "$lte": end_date}}).to_list(100)
    return document
```